# exe file from tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, exe

I developed an application with python tkinter to convert MP4 file into MP3 (see below). When I run the script in gitbach/terminal, the app works perfectly. I converted the script into an executable file. The process seemed to go smoothly, especially when I used the "Convert Video To MP3" button. The "Save MP3 As" feature also activated correctly. However,  When I press the button, the  message, saying "There was a problem, Please Try Again...." appear. This seems to be coming from  the except part from the MP4ToMP3 function I have created.  why is that, and where is the problem ?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

import ttkbootstrap as tb
from ttkbootstrap.scrolled import ScrolledText
from ttkbootstrap.dialogs import Messagebox

import openai
from moviepy.editor import *
import os.path

import os
from moviepy.config import change_settings
change_settings({"FFMPEG_BINARY": os.path.join("C:/transcriber/ffmpeg","C:/transcriber/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.exe" )})



root = tb.Window(themename = "superhero")
# App title
root.title("A.I Video Transcriber")
# Size the App
root.geometry('700x450')


# Create some global variable

global VIDEO_FILE_PATH,AUDIO_FILE_PATH

# Open video file

def open_video():
    global VIDEO_FILE_PATH
    # Open a video file
    my_file = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Open Video File",
        filetype=(("MP4 Video",".mp4"),("All file","*.*")))

    # print(my_file) this line of code would be  to show the path of my file in gitbach

    # Make sure the user selected a file

    if my_file:
        VIDEO_FILE_PATH = my_file
        # get the file size
        sz = os.path.getsize(my_file)
        #convert to megabytes
        sz = sz/1000000

        # Clear text box
        my_text.delete(1.0, END)  

        # Output  to textbox
        my_text.insert(END, f'File To Convert:\n{my_file}\n\nFile Size:\n{sz} mb')

        # Enable mp3 button
        save_mp3_button.config(state ="normal")


# Convert Video To MP3 Audio File

def save_mp3():
    global AUDIO_FILE_PATH
    my_file = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(title="Save MP3 File",
        filetype=(("MP3 Audio",".mp3"),), defaultextension=".mp3")
    # print(my_file)this line of code would be to show the path of my file in gitbach though it is not save yet

    # Check to make sure the user picked a file name to save
    if my_file:
        AUDIO_FILE_PATH = my_file

        # Convert to mp3
        MP4ToMP3(VIDEO_FILE_PATH, AUDIO_FILE_PATH)

        # Get the file size
        sz = os.path.getsize(my_file)
        sz = sz / 1000000

        # Output to textbox
        my_text.insert(END, f'\n\n\nSaving Audio File as:\n{AUDIO_FILE_PATH}\n\nFile Size:\n{sz} mb')

        # Make sure the file size is less than 25 mb as per OpenAI specs

        if sz <= 25:
            my_text.insert(END,"\n\nYour File Is Ready To transcribe!\nClick the 'Transcibe Video' button below")
            #Enable the transcrie button
            transcribe_button.config(state="normal")
        else:
            my_text.insert(END, "\n\n\nYour File Is To Large!\nIt Must Be Less Than 25mb in Size")


my_text = ScrolledText(root, height=20, width=110, wrap=WORD, autohide=False)
my_text.pack(pady =15)

# Create a frame

my_frame = Frame(root)
my_frame.pack()

# Create some buttons

open_button = tb.Button(my_frame, bootstyle = "light",text="Convert Video to MP3",command=open_video)
open_button.grid(row=0,column=0)

save_mp3_button = tb.Button(my_frame, bootstyle = "light",text="Save MP3 As...",state='disable', command =save_mp3)
save_mp3_button.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=30)

# Convert MP4 to MP3 using MoviePY

def MP4ToMP3(mp4, mp3):
    try:
        FILETOCONVERT = AudioFileClip(mp4)
        FILETOCONVERT.write_audiofile(mp3)
        FILETOCONVERT.close()

    except:
        my_text.insert(END, "\n\nThere was a problem, Please Try Again....")


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: it is good practice, for clarity, to avoid wildcard imports:
[wildcard imports](https://youtu.be/EueSSAyO3K0) pollute the namespace.